# Webcam not working on Microsoft Teams, installed via snap

Tags: snap

I did install Microsoft Teams via snap

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install teams-for-linux
```

But the webcam is not available for usage during calls.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You need to allow the access to the camera on Teams For Linux to be able to do videocalls, to do that you can use the Software Store in your Operating System after the installation of the snap. ([snapcraft.io/teams-for-linux](https://snapcraft.io/teams-for-linux))

After the installation, you need to connect the camera to snap manually

```
snap connect teams-for-linux:camera core:camera
```

Answer (score 6):

Goto Ubuntu software -> installed-> teams-> permissions-> camera on.